# Google Ads Conversion Tracking With React

Tags: reactjs, google-ads-api

I'm attempting to add Google Ads conversion tracking within a React App. In this situation I need to set it up to trigger on click as opposed to page URL. Within the index.html I added the Google Tag and the Conversion Event Snippet without issues.

**My Question: How do I now call the function on a React Component to trigger a conversion?**

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-______"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-______');
</script>
```

Event Snippet:

```
<!-- Event snippet for Payment conversion page
In your html page, add the snippet and call gtag_report_conversion when someone clicks on the chosen link or button. -->
<script>
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
  var callback = function () {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-_____/_____',
      'transaction_id': '',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a React component you can trigger a Google Ads conversion on click by using `window.gtag` as shown below.

The first AW-________ number is from your Google Tag.

The second AW-_______/________ number is from your Event Snippet.

```
const clickedButton = () => {
   
//This will trigger the conversion 

window.gtag('config', 'AW-_______');

window.gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-______/____________'});

}
```